# Poner un constructor como atributo JAVA

Tags: java, array, poo, atributos

Las instrucciones del problema dicen:

"1: Debe haber una clase Alumno que contenga SOLAMENTE los atributos de un alumno DEL MUNDO REAL: nombre, matrícula, correo, teléfono.

2: También alumno tiene el atributo del conjunto (arreglo) de calificaciones. Las calificaciones son una DUPLA: materia, calificación.

3: Debe haber una clase con contiene la DUPLA materia, calificación, la cual puede ser llamada Calificaciones o Calificación.

Restricciones:

RS-01: Las clases Alumno, Calificaciones, NO PUEDEN contener atributos correspondientes a variables de control, banderas, etc. que se requieren para la cantidad de materias, cálculo de menor/mayor calificación, promedio. En dado caso, esas variables de control pueden ser variables dentro de un método, o incluso dentro del método main() del programa principal."

**De qué manera es posible poner el constructor "Calificaciones" como atributo de "Alumno"?**

Lo único que se me ocurrió fue poner algo como esto:

```
public class Alumno{
    //Atributos de estudiante
    String nombre;
    String correo;
    int telefono;
    int matricula;

    Calificaciones cal[] = new Calificaciones[n];
```

n indica que en el método main se establecerá el tamaño del arreglo.

Estoy totalmente abierto a otra manera de resolver el problema

Comment: La pregunta dice:  **De qué manera es posible poner el constructor "Calificaciones" como atributo de "Alumno"?**   o es lo que pensaste como posible solución?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo más lógico sería declarar en el `main` un array de objetos del tipo `Calificaciones`, llenarlo y luego pasarlo en parámetro al constructor de `Alumno`.

Por ejemplo:

### `Alumno`

```
class Alumno{
    private String nombre;
    private String correo;
    private int telefono;
    private int matricula;
    private Calificaciones [] calificaciones;
     
    Alumno (String nombre, String correo, int telefono, int matricula, Calificaciones[] calificaciones)
    {
        this.nombre=nombre;
        this.correo=correo;
        this.telefono=telefono;
        this.matricula=matricula;
        this.calificaciones=calificaciones;
    }
     
     public String toString(){
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         sb.append(String.format("Nombre: %s \nMatrícula: %s \n", nombre,matricula));

         for(Calificaciones c : calificaciones)
         {
              sb.append("\t");
              sb.append(c.toString());
         }
         return sb.toString();
     }
 }
```

### `Calificaciones`

(según la convención de nombres habitual debería ir en singular, no en plural).

```
class Calificaciones 
{
    private String materia;
    private int calificacion;
    
    Calificaciones(String materia, int calificacion)  
    { 
        this.calificacion = calificacion; 
        this.materia = materia; 
    } 
        
    public String toString()
    {
         String s = String.format("Materia: %s \tPt: %s \n", materia,calificacion);   
         return s;
    }
}
```

Y en el `main`:

```
    Calificaciones [] c=new Calificaciones[2];
    c[0] = new Calificaciones("Java", 100); 
    c[1] = new Calificaciones("PHP", 99); 
    Alumno a=new Alumno("Juan","juan@mail.com",1234,1,c);
    System.out.println(a.toString());
```

**Salida:**

```
Nombre: Juan 
Matrícula: 1 
    Materia: Java   Pt: 100 
    Materia: PHP    Pt: 99
```